# Change img src from database with regex?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace

I have in database column content for example with this:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" align="center">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.cz/cz/katalog/some_product/">
               <img src="http://example.cz/article/3584/photo/some_product.jpg" />
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="http://example.cz/cz/katalog/some_product2/">
               <img src="http://example.cz/article/3584/photo/some_product2.jpg" />
            </a>
        </td>
   ...
```

If i make a mysql query to get this content I need change the source of image and href tag to another website (path is same) for example like this:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" align="center">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://anotherWebsite.cz/cz/katalog/some_product/">
               <img src="http://anotherWebsite.cz/article/3584/photo/some_product.jpg" />
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="http://anotherWebsite.cz/cz/katalog/some_product2/">
               <img src="http://anotherWebsite.cz/article/3584/photo/some_product2.jpg" />
            </a>
        </td>
   ...
```

I tried function:

```
    str_replace('example', 'anotherWebsite', $content);
```

but without result. Is any another way to replace it? For example with regex? If regex is the way can you show me how? Because I'm not good with regex. Really thanks.

Comment: did you do `$content = str_replace('example', 'anotherWebsite', $content);`?

Comment: Safer would be: `$content = str_replace('"http://example.cz/', '"http://anotherWebsite.cz/', $content);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace` should work. Are you sure you assigned the new value to the variable?

```
$content = str_replace('example', 'anotherWebsite', $content);
```

Comment: Jeez such a shame. Probably I'm still sleeping. Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Running str_replace on common terms is likely to have unintended results. you can be more specific by saying

```
$content = str_replace(array('href="http://example.cz/','src="http://example.cz/'), 
                       array('href="http://anotherWebsite.cz/','src="http://anotherWebsite.cz/'), 
                       $content);
```

This way it only replaces values that are part of a src of href attrbute.

You may also have to add rules for ' vs " as well.